# Android - Retrofit2 with Okhttp3 set custom Header

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I wanna add a custom header in Retrofit. But I don't know how to set it. any one can help me?

This is my code

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void save_config(final String ip_server_txt, final String port_server_txt, final String user_sql_txt, final String pass_sql_txt, final String token_txt) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
            String response="";
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("ip_server", ip_server_txt);
            map.put("user_sql", user_sql_txt);
            map.put("pass_sql", pass_sql_txt);
            map.put("port_sql", port_server_txt);
            map.put("token", token_txt);
            try {
                httprequest req = new httprequest(appconfig.URL_CONFIG_SQL);
                response = req.prepare(httprequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                response = e.getMessage();
            }
            return response;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //do something with response
            Log.d("newwwss",result);
            onTaskCompleted1(result, jsoncode);
            hideDialog();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: You should use the @Header annotation in your retrofit network interface. Its syntax goes like (@Header("param") String value, ... other retrofit items)

Comment: thank for your help

Comment: glad to help! (: